# How do I store data between requests in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

My application reads barcodes from a USB scanner. I treat them as tokens and then build commands from those tokens. There may be a situation that I need 2 or more reads before I can create a command. I need to store previous reads in some way. How can I keep some data between request? I do not to use that tokens in my view.

Only results of commands may be displayed in the view.

Answer (score 15):

The `TempData` dictionary is ideal for storing data between controller actions. It's most commonly used in the Post/Redirect/Get pattern but could apply here.

This is a good article to read about it: http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html

Comment: So, the thing about `TempData` is that it's intended to only live between two requests.  You can use the `TempData.Keep()` command to make `TempData` persist, however it's unreliable in an actual production environment - you can have TempData be intermittently missing, especially when doing AJAX requests.

Answer (score 9):

Here are a couple of possibilities that come to mind:

On the client:

- Cookie
- Hidden fields

On the server:

- Cache (make sure to use user specific key to avoid collisions)
- Some backend storage (such as a database)
- ASP.NET Session

Comment: What about when we want to preserve some data when a controller Action Method is returning a view which is posting a form to an external URL and then redirecting back to another controller Action Method within the same controller