# MVC HttpContext.Current.Items is null after clicking a link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there a limitation for **HttpContext.Items** ? if so what is the alternative?

In **FirstController** Index view I am setting an item.

```
public class FirstController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Items["Sample"] = "DATA";
        return View();
    }
}

<a href="/SecondController/TestView">Sample Link</a>
```

When I try to get the value in **SecondController** it is giving me null instead of 'DATA'

```
public class SecondController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult TestView()
    {
        string text = HttpContext.Current.Items["Sample"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`HttpContext.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx) *"Gets a key/value collection that can be used to organize and share data [...] **during an HTTP request**"*.

You need a stateful mechanism like Session to preserve data between requests:

```
Session["Sample"] = "DATA";
```

See also [what is correct way of storing data between requests in asp.mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336991/what-is-correct-way-of-storing-data-between-requests-in-asp-mvc)
.

Comment: I don't want to use Sessions. Can this be done using custom attributes?

Comment: Custom attributes aren't going to solve your problems. Explain why you don't want to use sessions and please click the "[what is correct way of storing data between requests in asp.mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336991/what-is-correct-way-of-storing-data-between-requests-in-asp-mvc)" link to see alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The `Items` propety of the `HttpContext` is used to share data in a single request. When you set the value to the `Sample` key in your first controller, it is discarded as soon as the request pipeline finish.

I think you are looking for the `HttpSessionState`, accessible through the [`HttpContext.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. You can replace the `HttpContext.Items` with `HttpContext.Session` in your code and it should work as is.

```
public class FirstController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Session["Sample"] = "DATA";
        return View();
    }
}

public class SecondController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult TestView()
    {
        string text = HttpContext.Current.Session["Sample"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext`'s data are retained in-memory for a single HTTP Request, then they are disposed.